# Specman coverage: How to cover range of values in a list?

Tags: cover, specman

I have list of structs `my_list`:

```
struct my_struct {
    comparator[2] : list of uint;
};
my_list[10] : list of my_struct;
```

The values of all comparators are configured once in a while. I would like to collect the range of all configured comparators, i.e., it does not matter which of comparators, something like this:

```
cover comparators_were_cofigured_event is {  
    item configured_comparators : uint = my_list??? using //How to define the item so the range will relate to all comparators values?
            ranges = {
               range([0..50], "Small values");
               range([51..100], "Big values");
            };
};
```

How the coverage item can be defined so the ranges will deal with every value in the list?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. You can only define items on scalar values. What you want to do is define an item for each element in the list:

```
item configured_comparator0_0 : uint = my_list[0][0] using
  ranges = {
    range([0..50], "Small values");
    range([51..100], "Big values");
  };

// ... so on for each item
```

You can make your life easier by using a macro to expand the code.